# how to copy a file without pasting to a destination

Tags: linux, bash, gnome-terminal

**Operating System**- Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon 5.4.10

**Terminal**-gnome

**Description**- I want to copy content of a file without pasting it to the destination file, is it possilbe?.I just want to accomplish it using terminal only

Comment: `cp /path/to/source /path/to/destination`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To my knowledge, you can't do this with vanilla Linux, but there are projects like [clipboard-files](https://github.com/larspontoppidan/clipboard-files) that attempt to do this.

It's got commands like `ccopy`, `ccut`, `cpaste`, etc, and works just by copying the files into a temporary directory.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions. Thanks.